# Sort Meteor Collection by date and only show past entries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to display a list of entries only if they are dated in the past. My goal is to be able to queue articles that will posted at a future time.

My entries all have a javascript date object timestamp when I insert them to the database. How can I make sure that entries dated in the future don't show up in my results?

Comment: Look for items less than `$lt` today. There really isn't a clear picture of what you are asking beyond that. See the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/)

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this to publish the data to the client.

```
MyCollection.find({ 
                   date : {
                       $lte : new Date() 
                   }
                  });
```

`$lte` makes sure that the `date` field is 
'less than or equal to' `new Date()` (the current time)